# how to make multiple accounts share one public_html webspace?

Tags: apache

Given Apache/2.2.22 on a VPS with cPanel, I'd like to have multiple accounts share a single public_html, like so:
`ln -s /home/site1/public_html /home/site2/public_html`

Obviously permissions are the big issue. Is it possible to configure users/groups correctly for this to work?

Comment: You can specify `FollowSymLinks` for that particular directory with the symlink, in your `.htaccess`

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't that only work for sub-directories within public_html?

Comment: It should follow symlinks to outside public_html I think. Usually better to use `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` to prevent abuse.